# Multiple conditions inside match MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to convert the following SQL query to MongoDB query:

```sql
SELECT count(invoiceNo), year, month, manager 
FROM battle 
WHERE year=2021 AND month='Dec' OR year=2022 AND month='Jan' AND manager = 'name@test.com' 
GROUP BY year,month;
```

I've tried to do so, but it seems to be incorrect:

```js
const getNoOfOrders = await BattlefieldInfo.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
     $and: [
       {
         year: periodDate[0]['year']
       },
       { month: periodDate[0]['month'] }
     ],
     $or: [
       {
         $and: [
           {
             year: prevYear
           },
           { month: prevMonth }
         ]
       }
     ],
     $and: [{ manager: email }]
   }
 },
 {
   $group: {
     _id: '$month'
   }
 },
 {
   $project: {
     // noOfOrders: { $count: '$invoiceNo' },
     month: 1,
     year: 1,
     manager: 1
   }
 }
]);
```

Because I am getting an empty array. But it should be something like this:

```
| count(invoiceNo) |    manager    | year | month |
+------------------+---------------+------+-------+
          2          name@test.com   2021    Dec
          3          name@test.com   2022    Jan
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure your SQL query is correct? 1. You need bracket (parenthesis) for month and year 2021-Dec and 2022-Jan separately. 2. Your MongoDB query filter for `manager`, while SQL query doesn't contain this filter. 3. Your SQL query need to group by Month & Year. For MongoDB query, concern on the syntax, the $group need accumulator operator.

Comment: @YongShun yes correct, thank you for pointing it out. I updated the question with SQL query and Mongodb query. I fixed the problem with error but now im getting an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, I think parenthesis (bracket) is important to group the conditions together such as month and year.

```sql
SELECT count(invoiceNo), `year`, month, manager
FROM battle 
WHERE (`year` = 2021 AND month = 'Dec') 
OR (`year` = 2022 AND month = 'Jan') 
AND manager = 'abc@email.com'
GROUP BY month, `year`
```

[Sample DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/horEr33AWHevzLStAFEn5a/0)

---

Same goes for your MongoDB query. While to search with month and year, you can do without `$and` as below:

```
{
  year: 2021,
  month: "Dec"
}
```

Instead of:

```
$and: [
  {
    year: 2021
  },
  {
    month: "Dec"
  }
]
```

And make sure that `$group` stage need an accumulator operator:

```
noOfOrders: {
  $count: {}
}
```

Or

```
noOfOrders: {
  $sum: 1
}
```

> Complete MongoDB query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          year: 2021,
          month: "Dec"
        },
        {
          year: 2022,
          month: "Jan"
        }
      ],
      manager: "abc@email.com"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: "$month",
        year: "$year"
      },
      noOfOrders: {
        $count: {}
      },
      manager: {
        $first: "$manager"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      noOfOrders: 1,
      month: "$_id.month",
      year: "$_id.year",
      manager: "$manager"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ebnbpARoq74)

---

**Note:**

Would be great for both queries to add `manager` as one of the group keys. Since you are filtering for the specific (only one) manager's record(s), it's fine. But without filtering for specific manager, your query will result in the wrong output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For some reason `$count` doesnt work for me. I get `MongoError: unknown group operator '$count'` error. But `$sum: 1` did the job